# How to make a vignette appear in an R package

Tags: r, package, vignette

I've spent some time making an informative vignette for an R package:

https://github.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr/blob/master/vignettes/introducing-stplanr.Rmd

It compiles fine in all the tests, but does not appear when I download it.

Test:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("robinlovelace/stplanr")
library(stplanr)
vignette(package = "stplanr")
```

Any ideas what's causing this strange behaviour? sure it used to work.

Comment: You'll need to set `build_vignettes=TRUE`, but there also seems to be another problem (non-portability?) with the code in the vignette. I just tried it with `install_github("robinlovelace/stplanr", build_vignettes=TRUE)` but it fails while building the vignette with a message that `cannot open destfile 'ggmapFileDrawer/ggmapTemp.png'`.

Comment: Thanks @JoshO'Brien , install_github("robinlovelace/stplanr", build_vignettes = TRUE) solved it for me. I'm interested in what you say about non-portability: seems to work for me. Any ideas on how to ensure it builds when on CRAN from install.packages()?

Comment: Glad that helped. I've got no insight, though, into how you could make it portable or into what's causing that error to be thrown.